# How to get Google fonts (Varela Round) to work in Polymer 1.1 web component?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, google-webfonts

**Question:**

In polymer 1.1 context, how do I include an **external font** (like the google font, or font-awesome) to be used for my dom-module?

> I am aware now polymer favours using style-module. I'm also aware the
>   technique to preload the font to an html and import that to my
>   dom-module. But I still can't get it to work.

**Goal of my `<circle-x></circle-x>` component:**

My dom-module basically give circles to these images with a `<h1>` below it already styled. Then under the flexbox structure to lay them out responsively according to how many circles there are.

[image]

**What I tried (TLDR version)**
I used `rel="import"` a `font.html` to a style-module then to my `<circle-x>` components, but can't use the font for style (it works when I used sans-serif), which means I selector it right. I also google-inspected it and the google-font stylesheet is loaded in the `<circle-x>` component page.

**What I tried (Detail):**

```
<!-- File structure -->
+ circle-x.html
+ typography-x.html
+ varela-round.html
+ bower-components
+ - polymer
    - polymer.html
+ - webcomponentsjs   
    - webcomponents.js
```

In the Polymer files, I noticed there's a file called the roboto.html, so I made a file similar to that.

```
<!-- varela-round.html -->
<link rel="import" ref="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round>
```

Then there's typography.html to reference roberto.html

```
<!-- typography.html -->
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../font-roboto/roboto.html">

<style is="custom-style">

:root {
    --paper-font-common-base: {
      font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    };
}
```

And I made my own version of typography-x.html for my Varela Round font:

```
<!-- typography-x.html -->
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="varela-round.html">
<style is="custom-style">
    :root {
        --circle-x-font-base: {
            font-family: 'Varela Round';
        };
    }
</style>
```

Now in my own module, called circle-x.html, I try to use the font, but with no luck.

```
<head>      
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>   
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="typography-x.html">
</head>    
<dom-module id="circle-x">
    <template>
        <style is="custom-style">

            .font{
                font-family: var(--circle-x-font-base, sans-serif);
                color: var(--circle-x-color, #353B39);
                font-size: var(--circle-x-font-size, 2rem);
                margin: 1rem auto 2rem;
            }

            .wrapper{
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                width: 200px;
                margin: 20px;
                height: 250px;
            }
            .img{
                position: relative;
                width:200px;
                height:200px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background-color: #E2E4E3;
                box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px gray;
            }
            .img img{
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
            }
            .img:hover{
                box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .placeholder{
                position: absolute;
                right:50px;
                bottom:50px;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a href="{{href}}" class="img">
                <img class="placeholder" src="{{img}}">
            </a>
            <h2 class="font">{{text}}</h2>
        </div>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
            is: "circle-x",
            properties:{
                img: {
                    type:String,
                    value:"http://www.placehold.it/100x100?text=IMG"
                },
                href: {
                    type:String,
                    value:"http://lightandlovehome.org"
                },
                text: {
                    type:String,
                    value: "test"
                }
            }
    });
</script>
```

Ultimately, I want to set a default font other than roberto for all my sets of elements, and use css variable to change them when I need to. Thanks for reading, I have watched/ read a lot of youtube videos, articles, and the polymer site/documentation but can't find a solution.

I Twitter @ebidel and he said I should use an import and gave me this link, but I felt I did. https://github.com/PolymerElements/font-roboto/blob/master/roboto.html

Comment: circle-x should not have a head tag nor should it have a script tag for webcomponentsjs (btw you want to use webcomponentjs/webcomponents-lite.js, not webcomponents.js... but only in your index.html file).

try removing those.

Comment: i think i see the problem (there are a couple) but there may also be a bug with font-family. digging into it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there's three problems.

The first is that your font is not being loaded because it has the wrong `rel`. It shouldn't be `rel="import"` it should be `rel="stylesheet"`

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

The second is that you're creating a mixin but trying to use it like a regular custom property. Read through this guide again:
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#xscope-styling-details

You want to do:

```
--circle-x-font-base: 'Varela Round'
```

instead of

```
--circle-x-font-base: {
  font-family: 'Varela Round'
}
```

But the third problem is way crazier and not your fault. It looks like the custom properties shim won't apply values with the string "var" in them.

```
--circle-x-font-base: Varela Round
```

will silently fail because it has the word "Var" in it. Try a different font name that doesn't contain the word "var" and you'll see that it is applied. I opened a GitHub issue for this:
https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2660

Comment: Okay, it works now! It's like you said, just include the stylesheet exactly from the google font, inside the element.

Answer (score 1):

I don't need any other font files or typography files. Simply, to include any web-fonts for Polymer to use, put the stylesheet at the top of the document of the `dom-module`. In my case,

circle-x.html

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mallanna' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<dom-module id="circle-x">...</dom-module>
```

Then to reference it inside the style tag inside your selector `font-family: var(--circle-x-font, 'Mallanna');`

I simply changed the font, like Robdoson said, [fonts start with VAR](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2660) cannot be used at the moment.